# Extraer información de archivo de texto en C++

Tags: c++, array, archivo

Tengo que leer un archivo de texto con la siguiente estructura

```
AREA I: FÍSICO MATEMÁTICAS Y CIENCIAS DE LA TIERRA♣1-12,i-60,100,300,i-90,

AREA II: BIOLOGÍA Y QUIMICA♣123-8,30-80,
```

La cantidad de folios es variable despues del trebol, cada uno se separa con coma; tengo problemas para leer cada uno por separado

```
string area, folio;

while(getline(ind2, area, delimitador) && getline(ind2, folio,',')) 
{
  string are(area,0,area.length()-2);

  if( are == "AREA I: FÍSICO MATEMÁTICAS Y CIENCIAS DE LA TIERRA")
  {
    string fol(folio,0,folio.length()-cont1);

    indSec[0][cont1].folio = fol;
    cont1++;
  }
  else if(area == "AREA II: BIOLOGÍA Y QUIMICA")
  {
    string fol(folio,0,folio.length()-cont2);

    indSec[1][cont2].folio = fol;
    cont2++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes editar y poner el código en formato texto en lugar de una imagen. Si no, te darán votos negativos y te pueden incluso cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba utilizando la función

```
strtok
```

Con ella puedes escoger un caracter para separar los datos, que en tu caso es **","**.

Comment: `strtok` pertenece a las rutinas de [tag:c], pero la pregunta se ha etiquetado como [tag:c++].